# How to implement the "redirect after handling POST" principle in a simple one-page Django app?

Tags: django

Consider a simple calculator implemented as a one-page webapp.
At the top of the web page are an input field where one can
enter arithmetic expressions like `6 + 3`, and a `submit` button.
After entering one such expression, and pressing `submit`, the
result (or possibly an error message) appears below the input field.
After each submission, the old output (result or error message) gets replaced with the new.

Here's my first stab at implementing such a page as a Django
app.  (I'm a Django noob, what can I say.)

The app contains only three non-empty files, the most important
one being `views.py`:

```
# calc/views.py

import django.http as dh
import django.template as dt

def main(request):
    result = error = ''
    expression = request.POST.get('expression', '')
    if expression:
        try:
            # of course, if this were a real application, I
            # would not implement the evaluation of the input
            # using eval; I'm doing so here just to keep the
            # example simple
            result = str(eval(expression))
        except Exception, e:
            error = str(e)

    context = dt.RequestContext(request,
                                {
                                 'expression': expression,
                                 'result': result,
                                 'error': error,
                                })

    template = dt.loader.get_template('calc/main.html')

    return dh.HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

(FWIW, I show the remaining non-empty files below.)

This works OK, but it violates one principle that is repeatedly mentioned in the Django documentation, namely:

> Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data.

I tried to comply with this principle by modifying `views.py` as follows:

```
# calc/views.py (version 2)

import django.http as dh
import django.template as dt

def main(request):
    result = error = ''
    expression = request.POST.get('expression', '')
    response_method = None
    if expression:
        try:
            result = str(eval(expression))
        except Exception, e:
            error = str(e)
        response_method = \
            lambda content: dh.HttpResponseRedirect('/calc/', content)
    else:
        response_method = dh.HttpResponse

    context = dt.RequestContext(request,
                                {
                                 'expression': expression,
                                 'result': result,
                                 'error': error,
                                })
    template = dt.loader.get_template('calc/main.html')
    return response_method(template.render(context))
```

This doesn't work: the page that gets displayed after one hits
`submit` shows neither the result (or error), nor the original
input string.

How should I modify the original `views.py` to comply with
the "redirect after handling post" principle (and still correctly
display results/errors/last input)?

---

Here are the other non-empty files in the app:

```
# calc/urls.py
import django.conf.urls as du
import calc.views as cv

urlpatterns = du.patterns('',
    du.url(r'^$', cv.main, name='main'),
)



<!-- calc/templates/calc/main.html -->

<form action="/calc/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="expression" value="{{ expression }}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<hr/>

{% if error %}
  <p>{{ error }}</p>
{% else %}
  <p>{{ result }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that you shouldn't really be using POST at all. POST is for modifying data on the server; you're asking the server for some information, namely the result of a sum, and that should be a GET.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks for your comment. When I replace `post` with `get` throughout (in the original version of the app, the one without any redirection), after hitting `submit`, the URL shown in the browser's location bar is an ugly mess (something like: `/calc/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=5J9hAyFWZsqZ3pH3FU0hnCYhfOV133W6&expression=1+%2B+1‌`​)... Can I avoid this (and still conform with "best practice")?

Comment: If it's a `get`, you don't need a csrf token. As for the "best practices" the reason it is considered "best practice" is to prevent issues with form resubmittion by refreshing. That can cause issues when modifying data on the server (like in a database). Since you don't do that, using it here is far less of an issue than your `eval`.

Comment: @Ngenator: my understanding is that the reason for the csrf token was to prevent cross-site request forgeries.  Are you saying that such request forgeries are not a concern when the request is a GET?  (BTW, as I pointed out in a comment in the code, my use of `eval` here is just to keep the code for this question as simple as possible.  It is not an essential detail of the question.)

Comment: They aren't, it's considered a "safe" method along with head, options and trace. You don't store anything, it's just generating something from the input. No user is logged in, no session is being manipulated, no server-side data is being modified. See here for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works